# Sitecore RTE: a custom button does not trigger a dialog

Tags: richtext-editor

I'm adding a new custom button to Sitecore Rich Text Editor which should enable a user to add a triggerable modal to RTE content. I haven't found a case quite like that when researching, but there is plenty of references which describe adding a custom button to RTE and I've closely followed [this](https://darjimaulik.wordpress.com/2016/11/23/adding-a-custom-button-in-the-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore-8-1/) one.

What I have done so far:

- created a new button in the core db for my html editor profile with `InsertModal` as a click action
- created `InsertModal` folder in `/sitecore/shell/controls/rich text editor/`
- created `InsertModal Commands.js`, `InsertModal.js` and `InsertModal.xml` in this folder following the instruction's examples and changing the name where applicable
- created a class to reflect the `CodeBehind` reference in the `.xml` and published the dll
- added this to one of my config files:

  ```
  <clientscripts>
    <htmleditor>
      <script src="sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\InsertModal\InsertModal Commands.js" language="JavaScript"/>
    </htmleditor>
  </clientscripts>
  ```

As a result, I'm able to see my dialog if I 
open it via `/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=RichText.InsertModal&la=en&sc_lang=en` link, but if I try to click the custom button in the RTE itself, nothing happens and there is an error in the console: **Uncaught ReferenceError: InsertModal is not defined**.

I'm able to see my custom config referring to `InsertModal Commands.js` in `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx`. Same error happens when I move the `Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.CommandList["InsertModal"]= function <...>` piece of code from `InsertModal Commands.js` to `RichText Commands.js`. I've tried refreshing Sitecore cash, but there's no improvement the code behaviour. Anyone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's what `InsertModal Commands.js` contains:

```
var scEditor = null;
var scTool = null;

Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.CommandList["InsertModal"]= function(commandName, editor, args) {
    scEditor = editor;

    editor.showExternalDialog(
       "/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=RichText.InsertModal&la=" + scLanguage,
       null, //argument
       500,
       400,
       scInsertModal, //callback
       null, // callback args
       "Insert Modal",
       true, //modal
       Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close, // behaviors
       false, //showStatusBar
       false //showTitleBar
   );
};

function scInsertModal(sender, dialogInfo) {
   if (!dialogInfo) {
       return;
   }

   var placeholderHtml = "<hr class=\"dialog-placeholder\" style=\"width: 100px; display: inline-block; height: 20px;border: blue 4px solid;\""
                    + "data-dialogContentItemId=\"" + dialogInfo.dialogContentItemId +"\" "
                    + "title=\"Dialog Content Path: " + dialogInfo.dialogContentItemPath + "\" />";

   scEditor.pasteHtml(placeholderHtml, "DocumentManager");
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the contents of `InsertModal Commands.js`?

Comment: @Teeknow Yes! added it to the end of the question body

Comment: I ended up trying the linked example and it ended up opening a dialog. The version I was using was `Sitecore.NET 8.2 rev. 170614`. Does it say what file the error is occurring in in dev tools (i.e. https://www.screencast.com/t/jRfKDded)?

Comment: @Teeknow thanks so much for trying that out. And your question actually did put me on the right direction to find out what's wrong, turns out I created a WebEdit Button instead of proper Html Editor button :(

Comment: glad to hear you got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I created a WebEdit button instead of Html Editor Button, this is why understandibly any of the button id's from `Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.CommandList` couldn't be triggered. After I created a correct type of button and placed it under `Toolbar 1` everything works as expected.